# why string nam is not inside in this dyn_sprintf command?

Tags: c, string, printf

I was going through a pre written program where I find sprintf command.

```
if(IFROOT){
str1="bicoted; diameter(d):;
str2=dyn_sprint(", distance=" GFORM, diskratio);
}
```

here, str1 and str2 are initialized as strings,
GFORM is defined as "%.10g" and diskratio is a variable.
IFROOT is a flag

please help me to understand how `str2=dyn_sprint(", distance=" GFORM, diskratio)` is working

Comment: There's no `sprintf()` in that snippet of code... And what is this `dyn_sprint()` function?

Comment: to be clear, `GFORM` is "defined" that way, as in, using `#define`? Do you know what happens in C when you put two string literals next to each other?

Comment: What is "string nam"?

Comment: @Shawn this dyn_sprintf() acts as sprintf having dynamic memory alocation

Comment: @ Karl Knechtel Yes GFORM is defined by #define. this is used to print the value upto 10decimal points
I have no idea about the second question you have asked

Comment: @MikeCAT string name is written at the starting, they are str1 and str2